# Was this chat ban justified?

Tags: support

@snailboat has been biased on my chat ban with our previous conversation.

The chat that snailboat is referring to here:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43883427#43883427

Is a chat about a *flagged post* (which I flagged) of Robbie's, **from English Language & Usage** as here: https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/283804 which eventually got removed.

It says this on the said chat too:

*Imported from a comment discussion on [english.stackexchange.com/questions/437536...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437536/why-do-certain-verbs-not-agree-with-the-preposition-for/439995#439995)

Comment: It's kinda weird though that you ask here. This has nothing to do with workings of ELL. I'd have brought it up on meta.SE. Anyway, snailboat answered, so.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it was justified. If I had been online and seen that flag raised, I would have done the same thing. How the comments got brought to a moderator's attention is irrelevant. Once a moderator is involved the entire situation gets reviewed and the steps needed to stop the disruption to the community are taken.

Your behavior in chat earlier that evening also ended up being brought to the attention of the moderation team, and J.R. did try to give you some guidance. If you want to avoid similar situations in the future:

1. Don't call people names, belittle them or disparage them personally.
2. Don't ping people over and over trying to continue a discussion when they have indicated they don't want to continue that discussion.
3. Remember that the community here are all volunteers. No-one is obligated to answer your questions, explain things to you until you understand them or engage with you until they understand your position.

When you reach a point in the discussion where you start to repeat yourself, stop posting. The discussion is no longer constructive, so just let it go and spend your time and energy on something more productive.

Answer (score 6):

The quality of the post that sparked the discussion is irrelevant.  No matter how right or wrong you are, rule #1 on Stack Exchange is [**Be Nice**](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice):

> **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.*

Your messages said "you're like a child" and you also called someone "pathetic".  This behavior is not acceptable on Stack Exchange.  Please do not pick fights with other users.

When I put the temporary suspension into effect, I sent messages to the other ELL mods as well as the EL&U mods, so if they believe my decision was biased they can reverse it.

Comment: I'd say the language went both ways. I wasn't fighting and in the chat I did reference to "how to answer questions" on stackexchange. I was giving him feedback on how to answer his question but he denied a one liner was sufficient for an answer. I'm sure the other people who consented on the flag of this post agreed to. The fact that you looked at an old discussion (we used discussion instead of commemts) just to ban me? I don't see that as justified.

Comment: What they said is also irrelevant.  Please take responsibility for your own words.

Comment: You looking for this discussion was irrelavant

Comment: If it was against the rules, I'm sure the mods at the time would of brought this up. Why are you bringing this up now?

Comment: Also the quality of the discussion that sparked the flag was not irrelevant considering **I raised the flag**.

Comment: @aesking - You just left three comments in response to one – a microcosm of the kind of behavior that put you on the radar in the first place. Enough with the playground retorts. As for that bit about you being the one who raised the flag, you're not the first to raise a flag only to learn the hard way that your own behavior crossed a line. In any case, you've asked your meta question, which gives the entire community a chance to examine the situation and see if the actions taken against you were biased or fair. Your arguments don't seem to be gaining traction; time to look in the mirror?